# "System running in low-graphics mode" after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have a serious problem with my first try of Ubuntu. Today I booted my windows10 pc to Ubuntu with bootable usb pendrive. I am getting this at first start

```
THE SYSTEM IS RUNNING IN LOW-GRAPHICS MODE
```

I can skip this and go to terminal window, then I tried `startx` command. messages appear and on the left side all are shown [OK]. But after that everything stops...

Then I tried updating the driver as explained in a related post. But due to no internet it didn't happen. Finally I tried to turn on the wifi and that also failed not happen. It says

```
Operation not permitted
```

I am stuck in this terminal.

My laptop is lenovo g-40 , 2GB RAM, higher then 2ghZ, 500gb harddisk.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 is a very old release approaching its end of life and it does not have updated drivers about anything.  Install either 16.04 which is the latest LTS release or 14.04 which is the previous LTS release and might work on your system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to a terminal, login with your user and password.
2. Your xorg.conf might be missing.
   Try generating the file:
   If you have AMD Driver (fglrx): `sudo amdconfig --initial` or if you have Nvidia Driver: `sudo nvidia-xconfig`

This should hopefully fix your problem.

Comment: No command found

Comment: Do you have AMD or Nvidia drivers?